# Is this the right way to check if a NSString is nil?

Tags: nsstring

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting the string
iapstring = [prefs stringForKey:@"stringVal"];

if (iapstring == nil) {
    //Action
}

if (iapstring !== nil) {
    //Action
}
```

The problem is in the 2nd if I get exptected expression before = token

Is this the right or wrong way to do it?

Comment: You've asked 7 questions and you haven't accepted answers for any of them.  This is probably hurting your ability to get an answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the opposite of `==` is `!=` (not `!==`). So you want `if (iapstring != nil)`.

However, in Objective-C, `nil` is just `(id)0`, a false value. So you can safely use `if (iapstring)` to test that `iapstring` has an assigned value.